# ActiveQT(Excel) как определить область таблицы программно?

Tags: qt5, activex

По идее дальше я должен вернуть хотя бы 1 объект, но увы ох и ах никак

```
m_excelApplication = new QAxObject("Excel.Application", 0);

    if (m_excelApplication == nullptr)
        throw invalid_argument("Failed to initialize interop with Excel (probably Excel is not installed)");

    m_excelApplication->dynamicCall("SetVisible(bool)", false); // hide excel
    m_excelApplication->setProperty("DisplayAlerts", 0); // disable alerts

    m_workbooks = m_excelApplication->querySubObject("Workbooks");
    m_workbook = m_workbooks->querySubObject("Add");
    m_sheets = m_workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets");
    m_sheet = m_sheets->querySubObject("Item( int )", 1);
    m_sheet->dynamicCall("Activate()");
    QAxObject* range = m_sheet->querySubObject("Range(const QVariant&)","I1:O9")));//указатель на ячейку
    range->dynamicCall("Select()");
    range->setProperty("Name", "Table1");
    QAxObject* list = m_sheet->querySubObject("ListObjects");
    list->dynamicCall("Add(SourceType,Source)", "xlSrcRange", m_sheet->dynamicCall("Range(const QVariant&)", "I1:O9"));
    list->dynamicCall("Add(SourceType)", QVariant(QString("xlSrcRange")));
    int count = list->dynamicCall("Count").toInt();//возвращает 0
```

Comment: imho должно же быть открытие или создание файла? и зачем делать hide при отладке? пусть будет видимый...

Comment: вообще, то я такие вещи сначала на JScript проверяю, это короче и быстрее, а потом уж в QAx